# blackberry remove default color

Tags: blackberry, colors, focus

How do I remove default BLUE focus color in Blackberry? I have one bitmap field and it is focusable. When I click on that image, transparent portion of that image focus with BLUE color and I want to remove that.

Answer (score 3):

This is a method by which you can remove the default color of focus. If you want to set your own color then you need to give body.

```
protected void drawFocus(Graphics paramGraphics,boolean paramBoolean) 
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try the follwing code

```
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("test.png"){

            protected void onFocus(int direction)
            {
                backgroundColour = highlightColour;
                invalidate();
            }

            protected void onUnfocus()
            {
                backgroundColour = Color.GRAY;
                invalidate();
            }

            protected void paint(Graphics graphics)
            {
                graphics.setColor(backgroundColour);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanx  . but its not working  . .do u have any idea ? plz tell me .

Comment: do you define highligt Clor eg:highlightColour = Color.BROWN;

Comment: The same worked for me in case of a ButtonField,I never tried for a bitmap,Also give color as your needs